# Does a for loop's while section execute each pass or only once in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

for example would this be constant or change with each pass?

```
for(int i = 0; i < InputStream.readInt(); i++)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
 for(int i = 0;                  // executed once
     i < InputStream.readInt();  // executed before each loop iteration
     i++                         // executed after each loop iteration
    ) {
    ....
 }
```

Comment: If you think I spoiled it all, feel free to rollback. :)

Answer (score 0):

It executes every time.  The `for` syntax is sugar for

```
int i = 0
while(true)
{
    if(!(i < InputStream.readInt()))
    {
        break;
    }
    // for body
    i++
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be syntactic sugar for `int i = 0; while(i < InputStream.readInt()) { //for body ... i++ }`?  Functionally equivalent I guess.

Comment: I put the condition in the while body becuase the question was about that statement specifically, and I wanted to make it as clear as possible that it really is getting executed every loop.

Comment: No, it is not. You need an extra block { around your whole construct } because else the lifetime of i exceeds the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first section is executed once before the looping starts. The second section is checked before every loop and if it is true, the loop gets executed, if false the loop breaks. The last part is executed after every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

For times when a control-flow diagram is actually the best graphical representation of a concept.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/For-loop-diagram.png

I think the main issue is the question: *does*

```
i < InputStream.readInt();
```

*get executed each loop iteration?*  Yes, it does.

In this case it's not changing any sensitive variable, the only variable actually changing in your code is *i*, but `InputStream.readInt()` will be run each iteration to make the comparison and will therefore run `readInt()` again on `InputStream`.

What about something like:

```
for (int i=0; i < xObj.addOne().parseInt(); i++)
```

*(given the method addOne returns a string representation of an integer one greater)*

Is my "check" incrementing the value that would be incremented if I called xObj.addOne() like normal?  *Yes.* and does it stay incremented to the next loop iteration?  *Yes.*

It's just like doing

```
 int x = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < ++x; i++);
```

This will never terminate, as ++x is always greater than x (which is also i)

What about a nontrivial example?

```
int x = 6;
for (int i=0; i < x--; i++) {
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

outputs

```
0 1 2
```